# Issue generating Service worker with sw-precache in react

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, sw-precache

I have created a react app using create-react-app.
Then I decided I need to edit/update the service worker code as per my need.

I am trying to build the app now using sw-precache (as its supposed to help building the custom service worker and automatically refer to the hashed static files).

This is the config I am using in 'sw-precache-config.js' -

```
module.exports = {
  staticFileGlobs: [
'build/static/css/**.css',
'build/static/js/**.js',
'index.html',
'/'
  ],
  swFilePath: './build/serviceWorker.js',
  templateFilePath: './service-worker.tmpl',
  stripPrefix: 'build/',
  handleFetch: false,
  runtimeCaching: [{
   urlPattern: /this\\.is\\.a\\.regex/,
  handler: 'networkFirst'
 }]
}
```

This is the build command in my package.json -

```
"build": "react-scripts build && sw-precache --config=sw-precache-config.js",
```

However, I am facing two issues after the build -

1. Even though I have mentioned in the config file that the service worker name should be 'serviceWorker.js', the build process is generating two service worker files -

   serviceWorker.js and service-worker.js
2. In the generated serviceWorker.js (build by the build script), 'index.html' file is not being mentioned in the precache (so the service worker is not caching index.html as intended)-

   `var precacheConfig =

   [["static/css/main.d35a7300.chunk.css","5cf96316c6919194ba6eb48522a076f0"],["static/js/1.6105a37c.chunk.js","ae3537cefdcf8ee5758c3af13aab4568"],["static/js/main.4857c4da.chunk.js","9d6cc8fb962129f3e8bc459c85d39297"],["static/js/runtime~main.229c360f.js","3b44b5daad3fcbefa8b355dfbc3d9630"]];`

Please let me know if I can clarify anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `index.html` in `staticFileGlobs` with `build/index.html`

You are getting two service worker files because the name you are specifying: `serviceWorker.js` is different from the default name CRA goes with: `service-worker.js`

Change your `swFilePath` to `service-worker.js` and that should fix it.